# Pepper Emulator doesn't work in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-emulator, pepper

I been working with the pepper Emulator in Android Studio for a while - now I switched computers and installed AS on the new one.

Current AS version 4.2.2 (as higher versions have shown issues with pepper emulator before)

I followed this description here to the T: https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-qisdk/getting-started/installing-pepper-sdk-plug#avd-graphical-option

Yet, the complete IDE crashes if I attempt to start the emulator.
The rdta-Logs show:

```
2022-07-04 20:24:29 ERROR ActionManagerImpl:111 - JDK: 11.0.10; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: Oracle Corporation
2022-07-04 20:24:29 ERROR ActionManagerImpl:114 - OS: Windows 10
2022-07-04 20:24:29 ERROR ActionManagerImpl:120 - Plugin to blame: Pepper SDK version: 1.5.3
2022-07-04 20:24:29 ERROR ActionManagerImpl:128 - Last Action: 
2022-07-04 20:24:29 ERROR ActionManagerImpl:103 - action with the ID "com.softbank.robot.sdkplugin.robot.connection.naoqi.OpenRobotViewerAction" was already registered. Action being registered is Open Robot Viewer (Open the Robot Viewer); Registered action is Open Robot Viewer (Open the Robot Viewer) Plugin: Pepper SDK [Plugin: com.softbank.robot.sdkplugin]
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: action with the ID "com.softbank.robot.sdkplugin.robot.connection.naoqi.OpenRobotViewerAction" was already registered. Action being registered is Open Robot Viewer (Open the Robot Viewer); Registered action is Open Robot Viewer (Open the Robot Viewer) Plugin: Pepper SDK [Plugin: com.softbank.robot.sdkplugin]
```

Even though the error shows JDK 11, as per Project Structure JDK 1.8 should be in use (see screenshot):

[image]

[image]

Same jdk version is found in gradle (compile and kotlin options):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}
```

In addition I noted that the JetBrains-Folder (usually found in %APPDATA%) was not installed along with AS.

Other advice I found online was to run AS as administrator - didn't work.

Could my issue have something to do with the Android Emulator version? As per Softbank "getting Started" Emulator.29.0.11 is installed automatically, to ensure compatibility. In my sdk tools this emulator version is not installed tho, and I can't find a download anymore either.

I'd be grateful for any help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try JDK/JRE 8 instead.

Comment: Thank you - JDK 1.8 is already resolved in source/target compatibility of project structure. Where else do  I need to change it?

Comment: Gradle needs to use it, then the plugin might work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still can't figure it out, added further info to the main post now

Comment: Could you provide more logs from `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Softbank Robotics\RobotSDK\Logs`? The issue is likely due to the plug-in, and should be unrelated with the settings of your project (Andoid SDK, JDK, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

The emulator is not depending on your project's SDK.
It depends on your system's SDK.

Which version of Android Studio are you running? The version you have on the new computer may be more recent and not supported by the Pepper SDK plug-in.

You might need to work without this plug-in...

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem.

I have struggled a lot the past few days trying to get the robot emulator to work properly.

They issue seems to lie with the OS compatibility, I was trying out different versions of AS and none worked with PepperSDK properly.

The only solution was to install Ubuntu as it is also found on this [thread on United Robotics](https://support.unitedrobotics.group/en/support/discussions/topics/80000657899) and follow some extra steps afterwards which I will also post below .

Install `Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3 April 7, 2022`

on `Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS`.

Install `PepperSDK`

Then run on terminal:

`sudo apt install qemu-kvm`

`sudo adduser yourusername kvm`

`cd /home/$USER/.local/share/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK/API 7/tools/lib`

`mv libz.so.1 libz.so.1.bak`

`ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so libz.so.1`

Hope it works.